# How do i remedy this error? Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded Error

Tags: javascript

I know what this error means but i can't for life of me figure out how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you all in advance. For more information; i'm a beginner to JS and would also like an explanation on how the fix works if that makes sense. This is code sample is just a small project for me in my spare time so please be nice :)

```js
// This function generates and displays to the console. Word1 - Random Number
function word1() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;  
};


//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion
var word2 = (function () {
    var verbArray = [];
    verbArray.push("Happy");
    verbArray.push("Sad");
    verbArray.push("Angry");  
    verbArray.push("Cheerful");
    verbArray.push("Ecastatic");
    verbArray.push("Depressed");
    return function() {
      var randomNumber, randomWord;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
      randomWord = verbArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
  
    }; 
  })();
 
// Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random Plural Noun

  var word3 = (function () {
    var nounArray = [];
    nounArray.push("House");
    nounArray.push("Cat");
    nounArray.push("Dog");  
    nounArray.push("Phone");
    nounArray.push("Computer");
    nounArray.push("Bottle");
    return function() {
      var randomWord, randomNumber;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nounArray.length);
      randomWord = nounArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
    }; 
})();

// Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random Verb
var word4 = (function () {
    var verbArray = [];
    verbArray.push("Running");
    verbArray.push("Jumping");
    verbArray.push("Walking");  
    verbArray.push("Sleeping");
    verbArray.push("Jogging");
    verbArray.push("Typing");
    return function() {
      var randomNumber, word4;
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbArray.length);
      word4 = verbArray[randomNumber];
      return randomWord;
  
    }; 
  })();
  
  

//Function to create password as one-line string
  function password() {
    return password('word1' + 'word2' + 'word3' + 'word4');
  };
  console.log(password(password));
```

Comment: `function password() { return password( ....` is recursive with no end in sight ... don't do that

Comment: How do I not do that?

Comment: why do you need to do that? just `return word1 + word2 + word3 + word4;` - note `word1` etc NOT `'word1'` since that's literally the string `word1`

Answer (score -1):

You make some mistake in your code.

```js
function word1() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;  
};

function process(array) {
  var randomNumber, randomWord;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  randomWord = array[randomNumber];
  return randomWord;
}

//Function to generate and display to console Word 2 - Random Emotion
var word2 = (function () {
  var verbArray = [];
  verbArray.push("Happy");
  verbArray.push("Sad");
  verbArray.push("Angry");  
  verbArray.push("Cheerful");
  verbArray.push("Ecastatic");
  verbArray.push("Depressed");
  return process(verbArray);
})();

// Function to generate and display to console Word 3 - Random Plural Noun

var word3 = (function () {
  var nounArray = [];
  nounArray.push("House");
  nounArray.push("Cat");
  nounArray.push("Dog");  
  nounArray.push("Phone");
  nounArray.push("Computer");
  nounArray.push("Bottle");
  return process(nounArray);
})();

// Function to generate and display to console Word 4 - Random Verb
var word4 = (function () {
  var verbArray = [];
  verbArray.push("Running");
  verbArray.push("Jumping");
  verbArray.push("Walking");  
  verbArray.push("Sleeping");
  verbArray.push("Jogging");
  verbArray.push("Typing");
  return process(verbArray);
})();



//Function to create password as one-line string
function password() {
  return word1() + word2 + word3 + word4;
};
console.log(password());
```

Comment: why did you change the IIFE's to functions?

Comment: I just try to make it more simple for him to understand what he did. I bring it back then.